# 1089 Leetcode Duplicate Zeros: where is the bug?

Tags: java

**Prompt:** Given a fixed length array of integers, duplicate each occurrence of zero, shifting the remaining elements to the right. Note that elements beyond the length of the original array are not written.
Do the above modifications to the input array in place, do not return anything from your function.

With this input: [8,4,5,0,0,0,0,7], the expected output: [8,4,5,0,0,0,0,0]
My Solution returns: [8,8,4,5,0,0,0,0]

```
class Solution {
    public void duplicateZeros(int[] arr) {
        int possible_duplicates = 0;
        //items remaining is total spaces - duplicate zero's
        //first pass to determine number of zeros to duplicate
        int arr_length = arr.length - 1;
        for(int item = 0; item <= arr_length; item++) {
            if (arr[item] == 0) {
                //Edge case: no more space to duplicate zero
                if(item == arr.length) {
                    //set the final index to 0 since it wont be duplicated just shifted down
                    arr[arr_length + possible_duplicates] = 0;
                    arr_length--;
                    break;
                }
                possible_duplicates++;
                arr_length--;
            }
        }
        //second pass to input new array, in place
        //from the last element of the new array, shift towards right based on duplicate count
        for (int i = arr_length; i >= 0; i--){
            if (arr[i] == 0){
                arr[i + possible_duplicates] = 0;
                possible_duplicates--;
                arr[i + possible_duplicates] = 0;
            } else {
                arr[i + possible_duplicates] = arr[i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be a good time to learn how to debug. Even if you don't want to use an actual debugger, adding print statements throughout your code can be very informative. You can take a look here for some tips: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I certainly tried to debug, but not to the extend of this blog post. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have realized already that your issue is with the case where one 0 should be retained but there isn’t room for duplicating it. You are trying to cater for this edge case in the inner `if` statement in your first pass.

```
            //Edge case: no more space to duplicate zero
            if(item == arr.length) {
```

Once you get to item 5, the third 0 and the one that cannot be duplicated because of lack of space, `arr.length` remains — 8, the fixed length of your array. So you are not getting into your inner `if` statement. The condition can never be true. I think it’s just a typo, and I think you can fix it yourself, so I won’t spoil it right now. (Once you have found out, I may add it here in case other readers are curious.)

Edit: as solution I am pasting your own comment:

> Thank you and yes you were right, all it took was adjusting
> `arr.length` to `arr_length`

A possible take-away may be that `arr_length` isn’t a good variable name since it reminds of `arr.length` and isn’t the same. I understand why you didn’t want `indesToLastItemToRetain` since it is long, but maybe you can think of something.

And I agree with Henry Twist in the comment: learning to use a debugger will serve you well.

By the way, it’s a well thought out algorithm you have devised.